# git clone password request and no repository found

Tags: git, gitosis

I installed gitosis on current ubuntu and it created user gitosis

I generated a new id_dsa.pub key and appended it to /srv/gitosis/.ssh/authorized_keys

It's both the same machine!

Now i want to clone gitosis-admin via

```
git clone gitosis@auedv18:gitosis-admin.git
```

problems:

(1) I am asked for password  (to get around it, i set one)

(2) clone fails

```
flo@auedv18:~/sc_git$ git clone gitosis@auedv18:gitosis-admin.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/flo/sc_git/gitosis-admin/.git/
gitosis@auedv18's password: 
fatal: 'gitosis-admin.git' does not appear to be a git repository
```

Should I modify the user and disable-password somehow? How?

No repo found - i guess I am in the wrong home dir after login?

**EDIT**

it works like that:

```
flo@auedv18:~/sc_git$ git clone gitosis@auedv18:/srv/gitosis/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move to gitolite. Gitosis is no longer actively developed.

However, you should be able to get a listing of your repositories by making an ssh connection and inspecting the output.

hope this helps

Comment: Gitosis may not be supported, but there's no reason not to use it. Still, for a new installation I'd likely use gitolite.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably set the home directory of the `gitosis` user to point to `/srv/gitosis/repositories`.

Comment: but it was set to /srv/gitosis by the ubuntu package and .ssh is there